# javascript - Can not empty div element content with innerHTML = ""

Tags: html, innerhtml

I have the following buttons and 2 function press() and clear(). press() can work fine but with clear(), i thought i did it right but it does not work. Can someone help me with this problem. Thank you very much. Here is my code:

```
            <div id="text"></div>
            <button id="7" onclick="press(this.id)">7</button>
            <button id="8" onclick="press(this.id)">8</button>
            <button id="9" onclick="press(this.id)">9</button>
            <button id="clear" onclick="clear()">Clear</button>



     function press(pressed_id)
     {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += document.getElementById(pressed_id).innerHTML;
     }
     function clear()
     {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

There exists a function in js called clear. Rename your function to something else. Maybe empty(). Don't think that is reserved.

Also `window.clear()` seems to do the job too if you keep your function named clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is correct. You just used the reserved word CLEAR as function. Try changing the function name to clear_text() and your good to go.

```html
         <div id="text"></div>
            <button id="7" onclick="press(this.id)">7</button>
            <button id="8" onclick="press(this.id)">8</button>
            <button id="9" onclick="press(this.id)">9</button>
            <button id="clear" onclick="clear_text()">Clear</button>


<script>
     function press(pressed_id)
     {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += document.getElementById(pressed_id).innerHTML;
     }
     function clear_text()
     {     
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
     }
</script>
```